# Solr - Previous and Next rows of current record

Tags: php, apache, solr, solr4, bitnami

Is there any special query in solr to get the previous and next record of
current record.
I am getting single record detail using id from solr server. I need to get
next and previous on detail page.

I'm using following addFilterQuery to get previous & next record id in separate query.

> id:[* TO $Current_Record_Id] // Get Previous record id
>
> id:[$Current_Record_Id TO * ] // Get Next record id

However above filter is not working when my current id is 0863810 Its giving me 0863922 08639** etc instead of 0863811, 0863812 etc to get next record id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Solr 4.7+, consider using `cursorMark`.

Yonik Seeley, one of the commiters of Solr, has [a blog post](http://heliosearch.org/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/) explaining Paging in Solr, and the last section of the post explains the cursorMark approach.

The implementation notes at the end are worth considering.

Comment: Thanks @Srikant but I'm using 4.6. Any luck with old version.